# Number of ways to choose $r$ balls from $n$ indistinguishable balls?

Tags: combinatorics

This question I'm stuck on "How many ways can I choose $r$ balls from $n$ indistinguishable balls" does not connected to any task. And it just appeared during the study of "Feller U. Introduction to Probability Theory".

Does this question connected with some combinatorial model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Why isn't the answer "$1$"?  All choices are the same, after all. (trusting, of course, that $r≤n$).

Comment: I think answer is "1", too. But I am very unsure about this.

Comment: The only way the answer could be other than $1$ (still trusting that $r≤n$) is if there were a way to distinguish the choices.  But, as you have written things, there isn't.

Comment: I suppose there will be an answer to this in the book, or is this some sort of exercise?

Comment: @ultralegend5385, this is just my personal thoughts.

Comment: @lulu, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just to make sure that this question is marked answered, I'm posting this answer.**

Since all the balls are identical, whatever set of balls you draw will be the same. Thus, the answer is $\boxed{1}$.

Have a good day/night. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D